# He isn't biologically my son but I love him as if he were

Tags: single-word-requests

So, I'm new here; and I know the title of my question may be confusing but let me explain.  I'm a writer, I've been writing nearly full-time for a year now and I am in the midst of writing a story that has an older gentleman who has taken a younger gentleman under his wing as if he were the younger man's son.

Since both are adults, the legality of adoption is not feasible; but as many people experience in life, they bring people into their lives and 'adopt' them anyway as either Aunts, Uncles, Grandparents, or even secondary parents...

My question is: what would be a good word that would describe their relationship?  I thought I had a good word for it but for the life of me I cannot seem to get it out past the tip of my tongue.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but note that in some jurisdictions (including many US states) [you *can* adopt an adult](https://www.legalzoom.com/articles/can-you-legally-adopt-an-adult); it's largely used for issues of inheritance, but also occasionally for sentimental reasons.

Comment: I have heard that kind of relationship referred to as "found family." I may make this an answer once I find a source, or someone else is welcome to if they have a good link.

Comment: As if he were the younger man's son or as if he were the older man's son? I don't get this part.

Comment: @MikeR: Right... or possibly "...as if he were the younger man's father"?

Comment: @psmears Yes, the way it's written sounds like the older man has become a son to the younger man. I'm not really sure if that was the intent.

Comment: You can say, as expression from the younger person, You are the Batman to my Robin. Most people will recognize it instantly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could describe the younger man as the older man's ***surrogate son***.

This is the relevant definition of surrogate ([source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/surrogate)):

> 2. A person or animal that acts as a substitute for the social or pastoral role of another, such as a surrogate mother.

Answer (score 24):

The older gentleman might describe the younger man as

> *the* [***son I never had***](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LikeASonToMe)

and the younger man might say his **mentor** is

> *[… a true gentleman and **like a second father to me**](http://www.etonline.com/news/184114_paul_mccartney_pens_emotional_tribute_to_sir_george_martin_he_was_like_a_second_father_to_me)*.

For a single word solution

> **[mentor](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mentor)**
>   a person who gives a younger or less experienced person help and advice over a period of time, especially at work or school
>
> Cambridge Dictionaries

Comment: The *second* in *like a second father to me* might be dropped, if the biological father was not so much *like a father* to the son (either due to absence or due to a negative presence).

Comment: Also, one might say, if like KRyan said, the biological was was not *like a father* to the son, that the new figure could be *the father [he] never had*.

Comment: role model is another word for mentor -- and is perhaps more suitable -- in this context.

Answer (score 10):

You might say the older man has taken the younger man [under his wing.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/take-sb-under-your-wing)

> If you take someone under your wing, you start to protect and take care of them:
>
> Ex: *I was a little bit lonely at the time and she took me under her wing.*

---

You could also say the younger man is the [protégé](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/protege) or apprentice of the older man, who could be considered his mentor or master.

> someone who is helped, taught, or protected by an important or more experienced person

---

Although you act like both men being adults is a problem, adult adoption isn't entirely unheard of in the world today and historically. [In ancient Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_in_ancient_Rome) men were adopted to further the line of a given family name and often by emperors to groom their successor. [In Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_adult_adoption) adults are adopted for similar reasons. For example:

> the world’s oldest family business, the [Hōshi Ryokan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C5%8Dshi_Ryokan), has been passed down through the family name for 1,300 years

Comment: It’s worth noting that neither of these *necessarily* has a paternal–filial emotional relationship with the mentor. Context would be necessary to indicate that. The words alone sometimes indicate such a relationship, but can also indicate a more professional/business relationship (though still a very close one).

Comment: Also note that OP used this phrase in the question, so this is not likely to be the answer.

Answer (score 5):

***protégé*** -- defined by [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/protege):

> A person who is guided and supported by an older and more experienced
>   or influential person.
>
> ‘Ruskin submitted his protégé's name for election’
>
> ‘His protégés were placed in important administration jobs; he was on
>   the boards of several start-up companies and advised others about how
>   to deal with the administration'
>
> Origin
>
> Late 18th century: French, literally ‘protected’, past participle of
>   protéger, from Latin protegere ‘cover in front’

A protégé is not **necessarily** loved as If he were a son, but the connection between mentor (see answer of @Mari-Lou A) and protégé can go as far as the love between father and son.

Comment: I don't think this expresses a strong familial feeling, to me it feels more like a teacher-student relationship.

Answer (score 4):

**fatherly** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fatherly)

> 1. Of, like, or appropriate to a father: fatherly love.

Answer (score 3):

> [**Paternal:**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/paternal?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)
>   characteristic of or befitting a father; fatherly: a kind and paternal
>   reprimand.

I also think Maybe **Godfather** would work.

> [**Godfather**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/godfather?s=t) 2. any male sponsor or guardian.

Although that has multiple meanings so that might be confusing.

1. a man who serves as sponsor for a child at baptism.
2. any male sponsor or guardian.
3. (often initial capital letter) a powerful leader, especially of the Mafia.
4. a person who is regarded as the originator or principal shaper of a movement, school of thought, art form, industry, or the like: the 
   godfather of abstract expressionism.

My go to thing to do, if I wanna find a good word for something, is type in words in these websites: [Word Associations Network](https://wordassociations.net/en/) and [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You might say the younger man is the ward of the older man, or the older man is the guardian of the younger man.

Comment: Though I do like the idea of this more than my answers, [ward](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ward) is going to generally have a connotation of the younger person being a child or a teenager, or possibly the younger person being incompetent to some degree.

Comment: Also, 'ward' just means that he is legally responsible for him, it gives no information about whether he loves him (or even likes him).

Answer (score 2):

In older stories that I've read, the younger fellow might refer to him as a mentor (mentioned above) or patron, although that implies a sponsorship, whether of money or of influence.

"father figure" would work as well.